# Determine if specific value exists in any level of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, recursion, search, multidimensional-array

For this nested array:

```
$status = array(
  "house" => "OK",
  "car" => array(
      "car1" => "OK",
      "car2" => "ERROR"
   ),
   "boat" => "OK"
);
```

I want to know if a certain value "ERROR" exists at least once in the array. I don't care what key it's associated with, I just want to know if the $status array contains an "ERROR" status anywhere in it.

Is there a cleaner way to do this than just iterating over the elements with nested for loops?

Comment: Do you know if there can be more than one nesting? Or is it just 2 layers?

Comment: Doing that HOW will you know which OK applies to which piece of information????

Comment: [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) does what you need (you still have to pass it a callback that puts `$value` in `$all`).

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem.  It would be better if you constructed a flat array of status results, so that this task was made much simpler.

Comment: @Riggs it probably doesn't matter.  I presume if there are any `ERROR`s, then the "submission" would be blocked from whatever "process".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the function `array_walk_recursive()` to get all the values with any level of nested array.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

```
<?php
$status = array(
    "house" => "OK",
    "car" => array(
        "car1" => "OK",
        "car2" => "OK"
    ),
    "boat" => "OK"
);

$required = array();
array_walk_recursive($status, function ($value, $key) use (&$required){
    $required[] = $value;
}, $required);
print '<pre>';
print_r($required);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => OK
    [1] => OK
    [2] => OK
    [3] => OK
)
```

Comment: `$all` will be an empty array unless you put it in the `use` part of the closure `function ($value, $key) use (&$all)` and remove it from the main arguments, just saying.  Because array_walk_recursive doesn't pass the additional arguments by reference, and therefore you cannot update as its out of scope.

Comment: Even then, you still are reducing the `$all` array because you are not recording the keys... Personally I say you can probably remove it "All" together, but I don't see how this returns a testable value.  In any case you will lose the nested keys in `$all` because `array_walk_recursive` doesn't pass them to the callback with array as a value.  [test it yourself](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57556303d6acfda3d0fb5db305a6b56b483e2075)  It only passes the keys with non array values, in other words it flattens the array out.

Answer (score 3):

I actually wouldn't use array recursive.  It falls short in a few key things you want to do.  And while at first it may seem like a "shortcut" to what you want,if fails in a few key ways:

- you can't return a simple testable value like a boolean true of false from the callback in it.
- you can't build the `$all` array with nesting, because the keys that have an array as their value are never passed to the callback. This essentially flattens the array out.
- it's not portable, or in other words it's not reusable as it's procedural in nature.

That said, honestly I wouldn't build the `all` array because it's pointless as you already have that array, so there is no point copying it. As I said I don't think you really want to rebuild `$all` but if you did you couldn't do it with `array_walk_recursive` even if you wanted to...

Anyway.

```
$array = ['zero','one', 'two' => ['zoo' => 'foo']];
             
   
function checkRecursive($value, $array){  
    $x = false;
    foreach($array as $v){

        if(is_array($v)) $x = checkRecursive($value, $v); //recursive

        if($v == $value || $x == true) return true;
    }
    return false;
}


echo checkRecursive('one', $array) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
echo checkRecursive('foo', $array) ? "true\n" : "false\n";  
echo checkRecursive('bar', $array) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
```

prints

```
true
true
false
```

Test it

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/78d0de421475b8e3104376c698027107e9b7e948

**UPDATE**
I see you changed the question and while you say "value" your array says the "key"

```
$status = array(
  "house" => "OK",
  "car" => array(
      "car1" => "OK",
      "car2" => "OK"
   ),
   "boat" => "OK"
);
```

Because all the values are the same.  So if you really want to find the key instead then just change it to this

```
function checkRecursive($value, $array){  
    $x = false;
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        if(is_array($v)) $x = checkRecursive($value, $v); //recursive
        if((string)$value == (string)$k || $x == true) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

A few things to note when checking for the keys, it's possible they will not always be strings, or that you will check using an unqoted number.  In these cases PHP sometimes has a weird way of changing a string into an integer and non-numeric strings will come out as `0`. For example `"1" = 1` but `"one" = 0` when taken as an integer. Therefore if you have an array with a key of `0` and you check for `one` it will match it because it will turn `"one"` into a `0`.

You can solve this by casting everything to strings. Or by using the `===` strict type checking.  I prefer the string method because checking with `===` would make `0 != "0"`  so if you tried finding a key of `0` with `"0"` it would say no match.  This is true of other numbers.  That is unless you plan on checking objects with it.

This is still an issue when looking for the "values" but it's less of one, because there you are not dealing with the native integer keys in an array, so there is a greater possibility you wouldn't encounter it.

It all has to do with PHP's loosely typed nature, it's a feature not a bug...

I put this small example togather:

```
echo '(int)"one": ';
echo (int)"one";
echo "\n";
echo "0 == 'one': " . (0 == "one" ? "true\n" : "false\n");
echo "1 == '1': " . (1 == "1" ? "true\n" : "false\n");
```

Outputs:

```
(int)"one": 0
0 == 'one': true
1 == '1': true
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df41f55251570a12d9ca693712bcdc785ad62f85